# How to call Nethereum Web3 slot0 function

Tags: c#, smartcontracts, nethereum

I'm quite new with web3 and Nethereum and I'm struggling to understand how to properly call smart contract funcion such as slot0, so far I have made, but it crashes within .CallAsync method code below:

```
var web3 = new Web3("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/SECRET_KEY");
var abi = GetAbi("Abi.json");
var pool = web3.Eth.GetContract(abi, "0x4e68Ccd3E89f51C3074ca5072bbAC773960dFa36");
var slot1 = pool.GetFunction("slot0");
var slotFunc = await slot1.CallAsync<Slot0>();

[Function("slot0", "uint160")]
internal class Slot0 : FunctionMessage
{
    [Parameter("uint160", "sqrtPriceX96")]
    public BigInteger sqrtPriceX96 { get; set; }
}
```

Expected result to return(example from https://etherscan.io/address/0x4e68ccd3e89f51c3074ca5072bbac773960dfa36#readContract):

[image]

Exception I receive: **System.NotSupportedException: 'Slot0 is not a supported decoding type for IntType'**

Almost related topic: [UniswapV3 incorrect price in slot0() sqrtPriceX96](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77793514/uniswapv3-incorrect-price-in-slot0-sqrtpricex96)

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem instead of using:

```
[Function("slot0", "uint160")]
internal class Slot0 : FunctionMessage
{
    [Parameter("uint160", "sqrtPriceX96")]
    public BigInteger sqrtPriceX96 { get; set; }
}
```

Change to:

```
[FunctionOutput]
internal class Slot0 : FunctionMessage
{
    [Parameter("uint160", "sqrtPriceX96")]
    public BigInteger sqrtPriceX96 { get; set; }
}
```